# Open Link in VSCode Will Create a New Web Browser Under Same Icon as VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, browser

I am using VScode version 1.45 with Firefox version 76.0.1 as a default browser (with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS). Whenever I tried to open a link in the VSCode, it will open the Firefox browser under [same icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVC4X.gif) as VSCode, and I cannot merge these tabs into existing Firefox web browser.

Same thing also happens when I try to run a program using live server extension. But when I use npm to start the development server, it will create a new window or tab under the Firefox icon.

How could I fix this so whenever I open a browser from VSCode, it will create a new browser or tab under the appropriate (Firefox) icon? Thank you.

Comment: Having been bothered with this for quite a while I started a bounty on it. I want to be able to open Github links from VS Code, but VS Code starts its own session of FF, which means I need to sign in to Github in that specific session, in addition to my normal session (daily sign in through company SSO). Doesn't matter if it's a link in the terminal or from the command palette, VS Code creates/opens its own session.

Comment: @Frans did you check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030176/ubuntu-18-04-launching-chrome-shows-under-the-vscode-icon-instead and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96829?

Comment: Fantastic, thank you @DipenShah! Took 30 seconds to fix once you knew how. Apparently an issue with it being installed from Snap, at least for me.

Comment: @Frans great! added it as an answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is already an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/96829) on VSCode's GitHub repository and as it is mentioned in the issue, origin of the [issue is in snapd](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1835024).

To fix the issue, as mentioned on aforementioned github issue:

1. Open some URL from the VSCode snap.
2. In the new window, navigate to `about:profiles`.
3. Ensure that the profile marked as "Default Profile" matches Firefox when opened normally. If not, use the "Set as default profile" button under the correct profile to change the default.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm!
Using the "default-release" profile made the trick for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I found this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1146012/1594495) the best solution

> You might have installed VSCode as a snap package, which causes
> $XDG_CACHE_HOME to be set to ~/snap/code/common/.cache, which could
> cause some cli tools to mistake that for your cache directory, and
> install/launch binaries from there.
>
> If you install VSCode from the .deb download, it should fix your issue

I removed vscode from Ubuntu software and download the .deb file from vscode site and install it ... problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Try making `firefox` your default browser thorugh firefox and also do check that `firefox` is your default browser from vscode

[image]

Comment: My Firefox is already is my default browser and checking the Custom browser in VSCode didn't work for me.